# How can I keep a variable-width column centered in a three-column layout?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a toolbar-like control. On the left, variable-size text. In the center, a small block of text. On the right, more text.

I want the center text to be centered, always, and only take up the space it needs. The left and right should expand to fill available space, then wrap.

Nothing I've tried works. Here are my attempts:

```html
 

<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<br/>
not centered:
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
   <div class="border">
  left left left left left left left left left left left left
   </div>
   <div class="border">
  center
   </div>
   <div class="border">
  right
   </div>
</div>
<br/>
not on the same line:
<div class="d-flex flex-column">
   <div class="border align-self-start">
  left left left left left left left left left left left left
   </div>
   <div class="border align-self-center">
  center
   </div>
   <div class="border align-self-end">
  right
   </div>
</div>
<br/>
left does not fill space up to the center content:
<div class="container row">
   <div class="col border">
  left left left left left left left left left left left left
   </div>
   <div class="col border text-center">
  center
   </div>
   <div class="col border text-right">
  right
   </div>
</div>
```

Run the snippet to see what I mean. How do get the centered text to be centered? (Unfortunately, I don't know the width of it in advance.)

Comment: Do you want the left text to go all the way up to the centered text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the left there is variable-size text.

In the center, a small block of text and it takes up the space it needs

On the right, more text.

The left and right should expand to fill available space, then wrap.

Is this what you are expecting ?

Use `col-auto` class for taking available space.
and you can predefine the with using `col-4` or `col-3` classes if the left should take the same width and the text should wrap.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row">
   <div class="border col">
  left left left left left left left left left left left left
   </div>
   <div class="border col-auto">
  center
   </div>
   <div class="border col">
  right
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try adding more text to the center column. Unfortunately it fails at a certain point.

Comment: @isherwood in question he has mentioned the center is a small block of text and it should take up the space it needs and no wrap that is why I did col-auto . And yes when we add more text and center the division doesnt wrap and it fails.

Comment: This worked perfectly for my app. The center text won't change much. Now I have to figure out how to make it responsive. It collapses nicely to a point, but then doesn't stack properly. Will try col-md-*.

Comment: @ccleve glad it helped :)